# React Native listIem passed props

Tags: react-native, listitem

I have a question about how to pass props for one screen to another, and display the props using listItem from "React Native Elements".

First i will paste the code of the screen with the "Add Friend" form:

```
const addFriend = ({ navigation }) => {
const [friend, setFriend] = useState('');
const [phone, setPhone] = useState('');

return (

    <View style={styles.container}>

        <Input
            placeholder='Friend Name'
            onChangeText={friend => setFriend(friend)}
            leftIcon={
                <Icon
                    name='user'
                    size={24}
                    color='grey'
                />
            }
        />
        <Input
            onChangeText={phone => setPhone(phone)}
            placeholder='Friend Phone Number'
            leftIcon={
                <Icon
                    name='phone'
                    size={24}
                    color='grey'
                />
            }
        />

        <Button
            title="Add Friend"
            onPress={() => {
                navigation.navigate('FriendList', { friend, phone })

            }}

        />
    </View>
);
```

}

Second, i will paste the screen that is suppose to show the list of friends i want to add, **here i cant find the way to pass the props from the screen above, to the list**:

```
const list = [
    {
        name: '',
        avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ladylexy/128.jpg',
        subtitle: ''
    }
]


    const FriendList = ({ route, navigation }) => {
        const { friend } = route.params;
        const { phone } = route.params;
        return (

            <View style={styles.container}>
                  list.map((l, i) => (
            <ListItem
                 key={i}
                 leftAvatar={{ source: { uri: l.avatar_url } }}
                 title={l.name}
                 subtitle={l.subtitle}
                 bottomDivider
          />
        ))
      }


                {/* <Text>{JSON.stringify(friend)} {JSON.stringify(phone)}</Text> */}
            </View>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find your parameters that you pass to your second screen in

`let {friend, phone} = this.props.navigation.state.params;`